# Eslint error on using callback hooks in React

Tags: reactjs

I am using callback hooks to stop the rendering of components that change due to a change of function passed as props, in every render. Here, I have added callback Hooks to `incrementSalary` and `incrementAge`. Callback hooks in this case seem to work fine. However eslint throws the following error:

```
 Line 10:76:  React Hook useCallback has an unnecessary dependency: 'age'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array     react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
 Line 15:5:   React Hook useCallback has an unnecessary dependency: 'salary'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-dep
```

If I do not include callback hook, and I click on any of the button. It renders all other buttons in the parent component. I believe this happens because my functions are not memoized and using callback hooks and adding dependencies makes my functions memoized. So only the specific button which s clicked is rendered. I do not understand why eslint is throwing errors at me, is it due to the wrong use of callback or due to the wrong way of using prevState?

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Title from "./Title";
import Count from "./Count";
import Button from "./Button";

function ParentComponent() {
  const [age, setAge] = useState(22);
  const [salary, setSalary] = useState(25000);

  const incrementAge = useCallback(() => setAge((prevAge) => prevAge + 1), [
    age,
  ]);
  const incrementSalary = useCallback(
    () => setSalary((prevSalary) => prevSalary + 5000),
    [salary]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Title>Use Callback Hook</Title>
      <Count text="Age" count={age} />
      <Button handleClick={incrementAge}>Increment Age</Button>
      <Count text="Salary" count={salary} />
      <Button handleClick={incrementSalary}>Increment Salary</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning/error that is coming for `useCallback` hook.
You don't need to add `age` and `salary` as dependencies in the `useCallback` hook. This is because there is no actual dependency on these states inside the callback.

```js
const incrementAge = useCallback(
    () => setAge((prevAge) => prevAge + 1),
[]); // Remove dependency.

const incrementSalary = useCallback(
    () => setSalary((prevSalary) => prevSalary + 5000),
[]); // Remove dependency.
```